# Running a string as a PHP code

Tags: php

I am trying to achieve something but i dont know how can i do this.

for instance check this script.

```
<?php

function runscript()
{
unlink('./images/a.php');
}
?>
```

which i want to run as a particular manner

i wat the script `unlink('./images/a.php');` to be assigned in a string

say for conceptualy, like this

```
$a = "unlink('./images/a.php');";
```

then i want to execute the script somehow to run $a which will eventualy run-

```
unlink('./images/a.php');
```

say something like this

```
eval($a);
```

How can i achieve this...??

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You do realize that this is a ***huge*** security issue, if the string comes from user input, right?  Besides, you've already mentioned [`eval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). What's not working with it?

Comment: If you need to run PHP code from a string assigned to a variable, you're doing something fundamentally wrong. Could you tell us why you want to do this? There is more than likely a much better solution.

Comment: why to take it into a string and then execute,its already executes in the function ,instead of that return true/false from the func

Answer (score 1):

Using eval is in most of the cases a security risk and evidence of a wrong strategy.

If you don't want to pollute the global scope use namespaces(You can even import and alias namespaced functions in php 5.6).

If you want to have the ability to move a function around in code (e.g. for a callback or a plugin-system etc...) you may use closures.

```
<?php
// php 5.3+
$a = function($file) {
    unlink($file);
};

// later:
$a('./data/delete.me');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you will be successful but you will try like this way. such

```
$a= unlink('./images/a.php'); 
if($a)
 {
  echo "successful";
 }
else
 {
   echo "not successful";
 }
```

may be it will help you. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could make the code a tmp file and include it

```
<?php
$code = $_POST['code'];
//uniqid for random folder
$id = uniqid();
$f = fopen($id . ".php" , 'w');
fwrite($f , $code);
fclose($f);
header("Location: view_code.php?id=" . $id);
?>
```

Then for your viewcode.php

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
//code to run then
include($id . ".php");
?>
```

Comment: Obviously have a page with a form with codebox name attribute is set to code

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`$a= "unlink('./images/a.php');";
eval($a);`

you can use eval() to evaluate string statements

reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php